Introducing Timing Constraint For Double-Clap Switch Circuit

I'm working on this clap-switch circuit and have already posted a question before. I've modified the circuit to toggle a motor with double claps. Here’s how it currently works:
1.A microphone receives sound, which is amplified using a BC547 transistor.
2.The amplified signal triggers a 555 timer, which outputs a pulse.
3.This pulse is sent to a D flip-flop IC, specifically the CD4013, configured to toggle the motor on or off for every double clap.
The problem I'm facing is that the circuit toggles the motor regardless of the time interval between claps. For example, if the first clap is at t=0 seconds and even if the second clap is at t=60 seconds, the motor still toggles on. I want the motor to toggle only if I clap twice within a 3-second window. If a second clap does not occur within this period, the flip-flop should reset to its initial state.
Could anyone suggest how to add this timing constraint to the circuit?

Welcome! Is this homework?

But why do you need a single circuit? It looks like you need two completely independent circuits, one acting on single claps only, and another acting on double claps only. Is there any reason you need to use hardwired circuitry with NE555 timers for this? Why not a MCU analyzing the mic sound waveform or even just the digital clap pulses to know what to do with single and double pulses?

This is for a project and we cannot use MCUs

@Mathew Are you allowed to use oscilloscopes?

If you are limited to 555 and 741, it smells like homework as this constrain would not be viable for a commercial project.

Why not simulate the circuit like most others? Debug at the sim level. You say you have created the circuit but, without resistor and capacitor values, it is meaningless. You should capture the sound of a clap using a microphone and oscilloscope. Nobody off the top of their heads will accurately and intuitively be able to say what this waveform looks like. The waveform needs to be known. Wasn't this question asked a few days ago?

The input transistor needs correct biasing.

@periblepsis no

@KevinWhite ok thanks

If I give you a complete solution, you won't learn as much. Here are some hints.
A timing diagram can be very helpful. A 555 in one-shot mode can be used as a de-bouncer, that is a good start. I have guessed on some of the time intervals. 1) how long before you look for a second clap. 2) How long before you decide if there were one or two claps.
Realize that you can't decide what to do until the longer interval has elapsed. This concept appears to be missing in your design.

FYI: When labeling IC pins, the normal convention is to put the function inside the box, and the pin number outside the box. The function is more important to anyone reviewing the schematic.
Hint: you need at least 3 flip-flops. Two that are never reset (or maybe reset on power-on). One remembers the state of the light, a second remembers the state of the motor.
You need to know if there were one or two claps. You could count them, but that would take 2 flip-flops. You really only need to know if there were more than 1 claps. This third flip-flop should be reset after the longer time period.
Edit2: As mentioned in the comments, you need to bias the transistor. The simplest would be a resistor from Vcc to the base. But it must be tuned for the gain of the transistor. If you are only building one that operates at room temperature, that is what I would do. There are better bias circuits, you can research them if you are interested.
The 555 will trigger at 1/3 Vcc. You want the idle collector voltage to be about 2/3 Vcc. It isn't critical, 60% to 80% is acceptable. Find a value for R10 that gives you the target voltage on the collector. For my transistor, it was 470k.
My collector voltage is 3.5 V. The collector current is (5-3.5)/1k = 1.5 mA. The base current is (5-0.6)/470k = 9.4 uA. Therefore, the gain of my transistor is 160.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Yellow is 555 trigger, blue is 555 output.

Now that I have seen the waveforms, the debounce delay should be closer to 0.1 sec, not 0.2 as I previously guessed.
R3 and C3 probably aren't necessary. A clap is an impulse of high frequencies, you don't want to filter the high frequencies much. A small cap might help prevent false triggers, so I used a very small value for C3.

I'm not actually following. Are you saying I need 1 flip-flop common for both fan and light ?

@Mathew - Flip-flop 1: state of light. Flip-flop 2: state of motor. Flip-flop 3: one/two claps.

First, showing pin numbers for the FF is not helpful. We don't know the chip, and even if we did you should not be asking us to go look it up. Redo the schematic to label the pins in terms of function. Same with the 555s. Next, you should look more carefully at your schematic - pins 2, 6, and 7 are tied together. I'm guessing you intended 2 and 6 to be tied, being D and Q*, but the rest makes no sense. And you don't want an RC on any input for this sort of use.
With that out of the way, I think you've missed the essential issue: how short an interval between claps counts as a double clap? If you know this, you can tailor your 555 to respond to a double clap as a single, longer pulse, and use this to toggle your FF. (Hint: retriggerable monostable)

I've labelled the pin
